# Entity Framework Migration fails when connection string is in custom config file

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, connection-string

I have placed the connection string in a custom config file called "Connections.config". And I have added an entry in the App.Config as

```
  <connectionStrings configSource="Connections.config">
  </connectionStrings>
```

In the Connections.config i have places the connection string as :

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="ApplicationDbContextConnection" connectionString="data source=;initial catalog=;user id=sa;password=;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

</connectionStrings>
```

When I run the Add-migration command in the  I get an error saying "No connection string named 'ApplicationDbContextConnection' could be found in the application config file."

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No connection string named 'ApplicationDbContextConnection' could be found in the application config file.
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_Connection()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_Connection()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbContextInfo..ctor(Type contextType, DbProviderInfo modelProviderInfo, AppConfig config, DbConnectionInfo connectionInfo, Func`1 resolver)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration, DbContext usersContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState, Boolean calledByCreateDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.MigrationScaffolder..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration migrationsConfiguration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.RunCore()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()
No connection string named 'ApplicationDbContextConnection' could be found in the application config file.
```

Other than this project I have several projects in the solution which uses 
 another DbContext.

Is there a way to overcome this while having the connection string on the custom "Connections.config" file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the solution I changed the start up project to the current project and the issue went off. Quite strange but it worked.